# comparing a mongo count() to a number, is it possible to optimize w/o doing the full count?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, count

i am learning that mongo's count() is not as fast as i thought. i have a fair amount of code like this:

```
function userInvited(userId) {
  return (Invites.find({inviteeId: userId}).count() === 1);
}
```

(assume the "invites" collection has an index on inviteeId and that the userId will appear only once)

i've seen that this count() is not much faster than just grabbing the cursor, i was hoping it was faster. even if i do something like this...:

```
function userInvited(userId) {
  return (Invites.find({inviteeId: userId}).count() > 0);
}
```

...i don't think it's going to be any more performant (and my loose timing tests have indicated so) because the count() seems to be doing the same amount of work.

i'm asking if there's a way to get mongo to quit counting once it find the occurrence, knowing it will satisfy the "> 0" condition.

fwiw, i am using Meteor, which doesn't offer the full mongo API, but i'm curious if there's a way in "full" mongo as well.

and if there's a better way in general to do what i want, please enlighten me.

**update:**

based on input from @tomsp, i've been using Robomongo's execution time to compare:

```
db.collection.find(filter).count()
```

vs

```
db.collection.find(filter, {limit:1}).size()
```

With a small collection size, execution times are comparable. i then ran explain('executionStats'). unfortunately, the find().size() said there was nothing to display. but the find().count() showed:

```
nReturned: 1
executionTimeMillis: 0
totalKeysExamined: 1
totalDocsExamined: 1
```

i have opened a ticket w/ mongo to see what they think.

**update 2:**

i reported to mongo support the results of my explain(), and they said:

> If it only examined 1 document and 1 key using the index (IXSCAN) then
>   that is the best you can get.

Comment: If the `userId` only appears once in the `invites` collection, is the index also unique (or should it be?). Irrespective of uniqueness, if you the only fact you need to check is a existence of an invite for that `userId` I'd try a covered find query with a limit of 1. For example, equivalent of  `findOne({inviteeId:userId},{inviteeId:1,_id:0})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ran:

```
db.collection.find(filter).explain('executionStats')
```

and found:

```
nReturned: 1
executionTimeMillis: 0
totalKeysExamined: 1
totalDocsExamined: 1
```

per Mongo support, i will not be able to improve on that.

> If it only examined 1 document and 1 key using the index (IXSCAN) then
>   that is the best you can get.

therefore, i will continue to use this technique to test for presence/absence:

```
function userInvited(userId) {
  return (Invites.find({inviteeId: userId}).count() === 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the mongo way of speeding this up would be denormalization. So you would keep that score somewhere else, maybe on the `user` object itself. Then checking would be as simple as `user.hasInvites: true/false` or even how many (`user.inviteCount: 2`) if you get my drift. You would update that number using a collection hook or manually whenever `Invites` changes.

Comment: yes, i understand. i'm not actually counting the invites for a user, but rather to see if they have an entry in that collection at all. i'm actually filtering on the userId and a groupId; the absence or presence of 1 record is all i'm after. i just want mongo to quit the instant it finds the first instance (there will only be 1, but it doesn't know that).

Comment: In that case and assuming you have an index on `inviteeId` you could do a `const userInvited = (userId) => !!Invites.findOne({inviteeId: userId}, {fields:{_id:1}});`. That should be pretty fast shouldnt it.

Comment: my initial test didn't show any speed improvement. i think i need to do some deeper investigation, i.e. beyond Robomongo's execution time (and on a bigger collection). is there documentation, mongo's or otherwise, that discusses this and why this would be more performant?

Comment: It's just a hunch since `findOne` passes `limit: 1`. You can run `explain` on the `cursor` to see if there is a difference (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#explain.executionStats.executionTimeMillis) and then compare `count` vs `fetch`. A large collection might be more insightful.

Comment: After reading this (https://blog.serverdensity.com/checking-if-a-document-exists-mongodb-slow-findone-vs-find/) I presume the fastest one would be `Invites.find({inviteeId: userId}, {fields: {_id: 1}, limit: 1}).size()`. `count` does not respect `limit`.

Comment: my Robomongo execution time is still about the same as the original find.count(). i ran an explain (i'll update my post w/ that info), but that only worked for find.count(), not find({limit:1}).size(). thanks for the info about size() vs count().

Comment: be aware that the the call should be `find({}, {limit:1})`, if you just use `find({limit:1})` it will query for `limit`.

Comment: thanks for your help. i have upvoted your answer. i will be posting my own answer w/ the comment from mongo support and keep using my current count() solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .find() query you should consider calling .count() directly on the collection, something like:

```
Invites.count(query,options)
```

You can have a look at the mongoDb documentation here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/

You will find also that you can pass the 'limit' option that allow you to 'quit' the count when the threshold is reached.

Comment: from your docs link: `count() is equivalent to the db.collection.find(query).count() construct.`

Comment: @tomsp, yes, i had read the same. i tested it in Robomongo, relying on it to tell me the execution time. they were indeed similar to what i have in the OP.